# Programmatically getting dates of time changes for the next few years in a given country

Tags: linux, bash, time

I was trying to find a an API, list or library to automatically list the dates of future time changes in a given country.

Basically I need a bash script on a linux machine that, if the day is before a time change for a specified country (like the introduction of daylight saving time), should trigger an action. I have it all setup, but how can I get a list of dates without having to insert them manually? I tried searching for a similar service online but to no avail.

Comment: You probably want [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Answer (score 0):

Read [tzfile(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tzfile.5.html) and [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) (and [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html)). Look into files under `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`

I understand you are concerned with [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Living in Paris (France) I am concerned by files `/usr/share/zoneinfo/CET` and `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris` (with the help of [tzfile(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tzfile.5.html) you could parse them).  My `/etc/timezone` file contains `Europe/Paris`.